# How to Split 24 hours into hour slab in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
'1-2 AM
2-3 AM
3-4 AM 
4-5 AM
5-6 AM
6-7 AM
7-8 AM
8-9 AM
9-10 AM
10-11 AM
11-12 AM
12-1  PM
till 
11-12 PM'
```

Total 24 row show.

Parameter is date like='07/06/2017'

what i am trying...

```
(convert(varchar,case when DATEPART(HOUR, START_TIME)%12<>0 then DATEPART(HOUR, START_TIME)%12 else 12 end) +' - '+ convert(varchar,DATEPART(HOUR, START_TIME)%12+1) + case when DATEPART(HOUR, START_TIME)>=12 then ' PM' else ' AM' end)
```

[image]

result is as per my needs but when any hours have no data then these hour not in output.
I want all hour slab whether that hour have data or not.

According to above output,there are shown only two hour's slot because only these hour's have a data.

Comment: What do you mean when any hour have no data? Can you show example where it does not work?

Comment: Actually, i am counting total numbers of call in a hour's wise.if 2-3 PM have 10 call then it show in result but 2-3 PM have no call it hour slot is not show in result.I am expecting 2-3 PM =0.I added  a result above.

Answer (score 3):

So if I'm right you always want to return 24 rows, one for each hour slot, regardless of data existing for that slot?  I assume you only have one row per hour slot in your data?

Based on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10986612/5320384), create a table with a row for each hour slot then outer join it to your results table, which will always give you a time row regardless of rows existing in your table

```
WITH Hours AS
(
  SELECT 0 as hour
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  hour + 1
  FROM    Hours   
  WHERE   hour + 1 < 24
)
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar, h.hour) + ' - ' + CASE WHEN h.hour + 1 = 24 THEN 'Midnight' ELSE CONVERT(varchar, h.hour + 1) END + CASE WHEN h.Hour >=12 THEN ' PM' ELSE ' AM' END, y.*
FROM    Hours h LEFT JOIN yourtable y ON DATEPART(HH, y.START_TIME) BETWEEN h.hour AND h.hour + 1
```

You will need to add a clause to the join to restrict yourtable to one days data

Note: you could replace the table in the WITH statement with a real table containing 24 rows, one for each hour if you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is still not clear.

> ```
>  you want to compare that calendar table with which table which column and how.
>
>     what will final desire output look like ?Throw sample data
> ```

You can format the output later on.

is this what you are looking for ?

```
declare @inputdate datetime='2017/07/06'

select distinct dateadd(hour,number-1,@inputdate ), dateadd(hour,number,@inputdate ) 
from master..spt_values
where number>0 and number<=24
```

We solve similar problem here,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257454/split-time-frequency-to-rows/44260448#44260448